# In Azure Devops Server, Download artifact via downloadbuildartifacts@0 too slow or fail

Tags: azure-devops

## Background

We're using Azure DevOps Server and encountered issues with slow downloads or 60-minute timeouts.

When adding the `downloadbuildartifacts@0` task in a DeploymentJob, despite the file size being only 200KB.

## Server Performance

The servers, Server A, B, and C, have taken 4 minutes, 6 minutes, and resulted in a 60-minute timeout, respectively, to download the same artifact.

All three servers are configured with the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

## Attempts to Resolve

We've tried the following approaches without success:

1. `downloadbuildartifacts@1`, but this task couldn't be found.
2. `downloadpipelineartifact@2`, which is not applicable to Azure DevOps Server.
3. Manual downloads through the browser using the API link,  work fine and at normal speeds (less than 2 seconds)

```
http://{{server}}/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/Containers/{{BuildID}}?itemPath={{ArtifactName}}&isShallow=true&api-version=4.1-preview.4
```

Given the results from method 3, we believe network issues can likely be ruled out.

## Workaround

### 1. using powershell download

Our remaining workaround is to create a custom download task using `PowerShell`

The solution take 40 seconds.

```yaml
steps:
  - powershell: |
      function Get-ContentRecursively {
          param (
              [string]$Url,
              [hashtable]$Headers,
              [string]$FilenameFilterPattern
          )

          try {
              if ( $null -eq ($AccessUrl | Where-Object { $_ -eq $Url })){
                $content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Headers $Headers -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 60
                Write-Host "[$($content.StatusCode)] $($content.StatusDescription) - Accessed $Url"
                $global:accessUrl += $Url
              }
              else {
                return
              }
          } catch {
              Write-Host "Error accessing ${Url}: $_"
              return
          }

          try {
              $json = $content.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
          } catch {
              Write-Host "Failed to parse JSON from $Url"
              return
          }

          foreach ($item in $json.value) {
              if ($item.itemType -eq "folder") {
                  Get-ContentRecursively -Url $item.contentLocation -Headers $Headers -FilenameFilterPattern $FilenameFilterPattern
              } elseif ($item.itemType -eq "file") {
                  $file = $global:files | Where-Object { $_.path -eq $item.path }
                  
                  # add if file not exists
                  if( $file -eq $null ){
                      $global:files += $item
                      Write-Host "Add $($item.path) to FileList"
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      function Download-File {
          param (
              [object]$File,
              [hashtable]$Headers,
              [string]$OutFilePath,
              [int]$RetryCount = 4
          )

          $retryAttempts = 0
          do {
              try {
                  $tempPath = Join-Path $OutFilePath $File.path
                  
                  $directory = Split-Path $tempPath  
                  if (-not (Test-Path $directory)) {
                      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $directory > $null
                  }
              
                  $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $File.contentLocation -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $tempPath  -TimeoutSec 60 -PassThru
                  
                  Write-Host "[$($response.StatusCode)] $($response.StatusDescription) - Downloaded $($File.contentLocation)"
                  Write-Host "Downloaded $($File.contentLocation) to $tempPath"
                  return
              } catch {
                  $retryAttempts++
                  Write-Host "[$($response.StatusCode)] $($response.StatusDescription) - Downloaded $($File.contentLocation)"
                  Write-Host "Attempt $retryAttempts of $RetryCount for $Url failed. Error: $_"
                  Start-Sleep -Seconds (2 * $retryAttempts)
              }
          } while ($retryAttempts -lt $RetryCount)
          Write-Host "Failed to download: $($File.contentLocation) after $RetryCount retries."
          $global:failDownload += $File.contentLocation
      }

      # Main logic
      $token = "$(System.AccessToken)"
      $organization = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)"
      $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
      $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}
      $initialUrl = $env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI + '/_apis/resources/Containers/' + $env:BUILD_CONTAINERID
      $outFilePath = $env:SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY

      $filenameFilterPattern = "*" # Example pattern
      $global:files = @()
      $global:failDownload = @()
      $global:accessUrl = @()

      Get-ContentRecursively -Url $initialUrl -Headers $headers -FilenameFilterPattern $filenameFilterPattern
      
      Write-Host "Prepare to download"
      
      foreach ($file in $global:files) {
        Download-File -File $file -Headers $headers -OutFilePath $outFilePath
      }
      if ( $global:failDownload.Length -ne 0 ){
        exit 1
      }
    displayName: myDownloadTask
```

### 2. using `Classic release pipeline` download

download via classic Release within 5 seconds. However, this means we cannot deploy through YAML.

## Seeking Solutions

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a solution or method to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task `downloadbuildartifacts@0` ([source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0)) works in `different` way with rest api.

If agent A, agent B can download the artifact `successfully`, but only agent C failed to download due to timeout. It means the ADO server is working fine, you need to check on agent C machine:

1. Is agent C in same network with A and B? If not, please try to keep in same network. Please also check the proxy setting if there is.
2. Try to `turn off` the firewall on agent C for a check.
3. It's recommended to check the [pipeline debug log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=windows-agent#configure-verbose-logs) and [agent diagnostic log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=windows-agent#agent-diagnostic-logs) for the detail appearance.

For agent A and B, the task speed 4 and 6 mins could be correct if
there's no error in both logs. You can also confirm the detail time the task cost from log.

Edit:

Regarding the task `downloadbuildartifacts@1`, you can install the patch(google devops server release) to update the server version.

Comment: I've attempted to delve into the source code you provided and noticed that it seems to be implemented using `Node.js ReadableStream`. When downloading, it might be done through `HttpStream` rather than `rest`. So, even though I've verified the network issue via `rest`, ensuring it's not being blocked, I can't explain the slow speed. From the pipeline debug log, a more evident error is seen: "Error getting: Error: read ECONNRESET".

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Regarding the pipeline error ` "Error getting: Error: read ECONNRESET"`, does it appear for agent C only? Or also exist for Agent A and B which is succeeded? It's a network error.

Comment: All agents encountered the same issue, continuously retrying download. A new test is to download via classic `Release` within 5 seconds. However, this means we cannot deploy through YAML. Another question: Why does `downloadbuildartifacts@1` not exist in the tasks?

Comment: Checked on my side, the `downloadbuildartifacts@1` exists on my ADO server 2022, what's your ADO server version? Suppose it could be old. You can try to install patch(google devops server release) for the update. In addition, did you try with class `Build` pipeline, will the task work? The error `ECONNRESET` could be temporary and if the task succeeds last, you can ingore. But only focus on agent C.

Comment: After successfully applying a `patch` upgrade to `Azure DevOps Server`, upgrading from version `19.205.33312.1` to `19.225.34705.2`, we observed that the `downloadbuildartifacts@1` task remains fully operational across all instances when using agent version `3.225.2`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to know it helps!  :) I add the steps in the reply to get the `downloadbuildartifacts@1` version.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to version `19.225.34705.2` and using agent version `3.225.2`, the `downloadbuildartifacts@1` feature is available and functional.

Note: before upgrades

- create a snapshot of the server
- backup the database

to ensure data integrity and recovery in case of any issues.